# Pass value from href link to detail page

Tags: php, html, variables, hyperlink

I have a table that shows all the users. I'd like to put a link around the usernames so when you click on a username it takes you to their profile page.

How do I put the username into a href link and pass it to the detail page?

This is all I have at the minute:

```
if ($allPlayers > 0 ) {
    while ($allPlayersItem = mysqli_fetch_assoc($playersQuery)) {
        echo "<a href='detailpage.php'>".$allPlayersItem['gamertag']."</a>";
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the player's `gamertag` to a query parameter for example:

```
echo "<a href='detailpage.php?player={$allPlayersItem['gamertag']}'>".$allPlayersItem['gamertag']."</a>";
```

Then in `detailpage.php` you can write:

```
$player = $_GET['player'] ?? '';
if ($player != '') {
     // display player details...
}
```

Note that if the `gamertag` value may contain special characters then you should [`urlencode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the value before using it as a parameter i.e.

```
echo "<a href='detailpage.php?player=" . urlencode($allPlayersItem['gamertag']) . "'>".$allPlayersItem['gamertag']."</a>";
```

Comment: Thanks for your timely response nick! (sorry pressed enter and it posted my comment before i was finished)
How would I display the player details? I'm trying to filter an sql database to show only one user's info. Would I still need to write the sql query with the $_GET on the detail page?

Comment: @TaylorPreston we've all done that! Yes, you would write the SQL query to fetch the player's profile details inside the `if` block in `detailpage.php`.

Comment: Nick, Thank you so much for all that!

Comment: @TaylorPreston no worries. If you have issues with writing the profile page, please ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest you to split the responsability of getting the data from the DB and the rendering the data. The most common approach for that it could be following the MVC pattern.

Something like:

```
# Controller/PlayerController
final class PlayerController
{
    public function index(): Response
    {
        $players = [/* list of players to display. From the DB, for example*/];

        return $this->render('player/index.[blade|twig|php]', $players);
    }
}

# Views/player/index.php
<?php foreach ($players as $player): ?>
    <a href='detailpage.php'>" . <?= $player['gamertag']?> . "</a><br>"
<?php endforeach ?>
```

I recommend you to research and learn more about this topic using [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20mvc%20pattern%20example), for exmaple.